# Fabric.js - how to use custom cursors without drawing mode

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, fabricjs

I have no idea how to set up cursor image for drawing on the Canvas. I have noticed that I can set it only when

`FABRICCANVAS.isDrawingMode = true;`

However, the problem is that I have created dedicated drawing tools and I don't want to use those that are built into the Fabric.js.

Sample of my code (which doesn't work properly):

```
const FABRICCANVAS = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-draft');
const DRAFT = document.querySelector(".upper-canvas");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    DRAFT.style.cursor = 'url(img/cursors/image.png) 0 34, auto';
});
```

But when I set `isDrawingMode` to true, it works. Unfortunately, I don't want to use built-in drawing tools because they leave paths (that can then be moved later, when `FABRICCANVAS.selection = true`).

Do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: onhover of canvas you want your custom cursor ??

Comment: Yes, precisely. It could be an image of chalk for example.

Comment: for drawing you are using pencilBrush ?

Comment: No, I created my own tools for drawing (not available in Fabric.js).

Comment: `FABRICCANVAS.hoverCursor = 'url(img/cursors/image.png) 0 34, auto'; ` use like this.

Comment: It works only if I set `FABRICCANVAS.isDrawingMode` to `true`, but I can't do this.

Comment: That will work on hover of canvas.

Comment: Hmm, It works but if I move cursor it will change back to `default`.

Answer (score 0):

For the Canvas you can set different cursors:

e.g.

```
canvas.hoverCursor
canvas.defaultCursor
canvas.moveCursor
```

You can use absolute or relative paths to your cursor image:

```
canvas.moveCursor = 'url("...") 10 10, crosshair';
```